# angular - stop two way binding or local value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to NOT bind javascript local value to $scope function automatically, but angular did.

javascript code

```
    var startat = true;
    $scope.chagneStart = function() { startat = !startat}
    $scope.isStart = function() { return angular.copy( startat); }
```

html code

```
<checkbox ng-click="chagneStartAt()">
<tr ng-show="isStartAt()"> ... </tr>
```

When I cliked checkbox, tr tag would be show or not depend on *start value*. I want to NOT change tr tag until call some other function, like applyOption().

Comment: Your question is not clear to me :)

Comment: Provide your html code too.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. I added some html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the function inside `<tr></tr>` tag  (**ng-show="isStartAt()"**) which is incorrect here.

Actually, what happens, it calls the function repeatedly. You can check this by keeping `console.log('')` in your function named **isStartAt()**.

So when you click on checkbox, the function **chagneStart()** gets called. And it updates the value of var **startat**. And because your  tag function **isStartAt()** is calling repeatedly, so it also returns the updated value of **startat**.

So just replace your code with the below one.

**Controller**

```
 var startat = true;
 $scope.chagneStart = function() { startat = !startat}
 $scope.isStart = angular.copy(startat);
```

**HTML**

```
<checkbox ng-click="chagneStartAt()">
<tr ng-show="isStartAt"> ... </t
```

Answer (score 1):

At this case you should have `oldStartat` variable:

**Javascript:**

```
var startat, oldStartat = true;    
$scope.chagneStart = function() { startat = !startat}
$scope.applyOption = function() { oldStartat = startat; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<checkbox ng-click="chagneStart()">
<tr ng-show="oldStartat">...</tr>
<input type='button' ng-click='applyOption()' value='Apply'>
```